# Django - Dynamically assign initial value to form from other fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a Django app. I would like to know it it's possible (I haven't seen anywhere that it is) to create a form which has initial values that can change depending on selections in other fields. To be more specific, I have a field which is a drop-down menu of standard cosmologies, each of which has a certain set of parameters. These parameters are fields of their own. I want to set the initial values of these parameters after the user has selected a specific option from the drop-down menu. If possible, they should also be greyed out (ie. not changeable) when this is done (there is one option in the dropdown which is 'Custom', for which they should be editable).

I hope that's enough information. Cheers.

Comment: You can make a standard Django form and handle the conditional initial values in javascript you write yourself. I don't know of any Django-specific helpers that will make that process easier.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to do this or a tutorial to help? I have basically no experience with django and absolutely none with javascript.

Comment: You may want to have look at https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: That looks interesting.. would it also work with normal form fields (not models)?